# In Chrome Only: Part of the ViewState is added before the header of the next call

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, viewstate

We are trying to track down an issue that is happening with our ASP.NET Application, but only one one environment, and only in Chrome, not IE.

The problem is that some (only a small portion) of the view state is showing up in the request header, and its all in caps.  The ViewState is from the previous request.

Here is the Request:

```
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%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%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 http://xxx.xxx.xxx/viewconfig.aspx?config=4&application=CME HTTP/1.1
    Host: xxx.xxx.xxx
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx/viewconfig.aspx?config=4&application=CME
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4
    Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=y1g2g5wqzjs42hjj50lqitf2
```

And here is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 15:22:44 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 326

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

[image]
What do you think this may be, and how do you think that we can fix it?  It works fine in IE and FireFox

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have the exactly the same issue. it only happens to Chrome but not IE or FF. (even not earlier version of chrome 49.0.2623.87 m, the current chrome version I am using is 55.0.2883.87 m).

Until chrome fixes this bug, here is the workaround I did to fix the issue, add
EnableViewState="false" to aspx Page tag.